# Implementing Bellman Ford Algorithm in Distance Vector Routing Protocol

Tags: python, sockets, udp, nodes, bellman-ford

I cannot get the code to work for then the cost increases. I use the following functions in the code:

1. UpdateRouteCost: This command takes two parameters, neighbor name and cost. For example, when user input the command UpdateRouteCost nodeB 4, your program should be able to update the corresponding link cost from this node to nodeB to 4.
2. ReConstructRoutingTable: This is the function that should be used to execute BellmanFord algorithm and update the routing table based on UpdateRouteCost or receving an update from your neighbors.
3. SendUpdate: This is the function that should be called whenever the node have updated your routing table.
4. HandleMessage: This is the function that should be called whenever the node receives a message from your neighbors.

To run the code you must open all 3 nodes by opening python3 node.py a.ini python3 node.py b.ini python3 node.py c.ini all simultaneously at once. Then you can update the cost and the routing table.

node.py in python 3

```
    import socket
import json
import operator
import sys
import binascii
import struct
import threading
import configparser


def is_diff(obj1,obj2):
    if obj1 == None or obj2 == None:
        return False
    for k in obj1:
        if k == 'node':
            continue
        if obj1[k]['cost'] != obj2[k]['cost']:
            return True
    return False

def print_table(obj):
    if obj == None:
        print(">>>>>> table is empty <<<<<<<<")
        return
    dest1 = obj['link1']['name']
    cost1 = obj['link1']['cost']
    next_hop1 = obj['link1']['name']

    dest2 = obj['link2']['name']
    cost2 = obj['link2']['cost']
    next_hop2 = obj['link2']['name']

    print('>>>> ' + obj['node']['name'] + ' routing table <<<<')
    print('-------------------------------------------------------')
    print('|   destination   |    link cost    |    next hop     |')
    print('|    %-13s|    %-13s|    %-13s|' % (dest1,cost1,next_hop1))
    print('|    %-13s|    %-13s|    %-13s|' % (dest2,cost2,next_hop2))
    print('-------------------------------------------------------')

def print_diff(obj1,obj2):
    if obj1 == None or obj2 == None:
        return
    if is_diff(obj1,obj2):
        print("Before Update Table")
        print_table(obj1)
        print("After Update Table")
        print_table(obj2)

        for k in obj1:
            if k == "node":
                continue
            if obj2[k]['cost'] != obj1[k]['cost']:
                print("Node " + obj2[k]['name'] + " cost changed from " + str(obj1[k]['cost']) + " to " + str(obj2[k]['cost']))
    else:
        print("Node " + obj1['node']['name'] + " routing table not changed")

def save_table(table):
    global node_configs
    node_configs[table['node']['name']] = table

def listen_thread(port):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.bind(("0.0.0.0", port))
    while True:
        data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
        print(data)

class RecvThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,port):
        super(RecvThread, self).__init__()
        self.port = port

    def run(self):
        global node_configs
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        s.bind(("0.0.0.0", self.port))
        while True:
            data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
            print("Recv: ");
            dict = json.loads(str(data,encoding='utf-8'))
            print_table(dict)
            name = dict['node']['name']
            old = None
            if name in node_configs:
                old = node_configs[name]
            save_table(dict)
            print_diff(old,dict)
            handle_message(dict)
            print("Input command(FirstLoad,FirstSend,Bye,MyRoutingTable,UpdateRouteCost):")

class MyParser(configparser.ConfigParser):
    def as_dict(self):
        d = dict(self._sections)
        for k in d:
            d[k] = dict(d[k])
            d[k].pop('__name__', None)
        return d

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print("Useage: python " + sys.argv[0] + " <confg file>")
    sys.exit(-1)

def load_ini(file):
    cf = MyParser()
    cf.read(file)
    return cf.as_dict()

config_dict = load_ini(sys.argv[1])
listen_port = int(config_dict['node']['port'])
#run recv thread
t = RecvThread(int(listen_port))
t.setDaemon(True)
t.start()

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

node_configs = {}

def reconstruct(obj):
    change = False
    name1 = config_dict['node']['name']
    name2 = obj['node']['name']
    for j in config_dict:
        if config_dict[j]['name'] == name2:
            link = j
            cost = int(config_dict[j]['cost'])
    for k in obj:
        link = obj[k]
        link_name = link['name']
        if k == "node":
            continue
        else:
            for i in config_dict:
                test_node = config_dict[i]
                test_name = test_node['name']
                if i == "node":
                    continue
                elif test_name == name2 and link_name == name1:
                    if test_node['cost'] != link['cost']:
                        test_node['cost'] = link['cost']
                        change = True
                elif test_name == link_name:
                    a = int(test_node['cost'])
                    b = int(link['cost']) + cost
                    if a > b:
                        test_node['cost'] = b
                        change = True
    if change:
        send()

def handle_message(obj):
    reconstruct(obj)

def send():
    global s
    #send to link1
    s.sendto(bytes(json.dumps(config_dict),'utf8'),(config_dict['link1']['ip'],int(config_dict['link1']['port'])))
    #send to link2
    s.sendto(bytes(json.dumps(config_dict),'utf8'),(config_dict['link2']['ip'],int(config_dict['link2']['port'])))
    print("Send config finished")


def load(ini):
    config_dict = load_ini(ini)
    print("Load config file finished")

def update_cost(node,cost):
    if not cost.isdigit():
        print("Cost is not number")
        return
    found = False
    for k in config_dict:
        if k == "node":
            continue
        v = config_dict[k]
        tmp_name = v['name']
        if tmp_name == node:
            v['cost'] = cost
            found = True
    if not found:
        print("Node <" + node  + "> not found in table")
    else:
        send()

while True:
    print("Input command(FirstLoad,FirstSend,Bye,MyRoutingTable,UpdateRouteCost):")
    text = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
    if text == "FirstSend":
        send()
    elif text == "FirstLoad":
        load(sys.argv[1])
    elif text == "Bye":
        break
    elif text == "MyRoutingTable":
        print_table(config_dict)
    elif text.startswith("UpdateRouteCost"):
        cmds = text.split(" ")
        if len(cmds) != 3:
            print("Update command usage:UpdateRouteCost <node name> <cost>")
            continue
        name = cmds[1]
        cost = cmds[2]
        update_cost(name,cost)
    else:
        print("Invalid command")
```

a.ini

```
[node]
name=nodeA
port=1025

[link1]
name=nodeB
ip=127.0.0.1
port=1027
cost=4

[link2]
name=nodeC
ip=127.0.0.1
port=1029
cost=10
```

b.ini

```
[node]
name=nodeB
port=1027

[link1]
name=nodeA
ip=127.0.0.1
port=1025
cost=4

[link2]
name=nodeC
ip=127.0.0.1
port=1029
cost=1
```

c.ini

```
[node]
name=nodeC
port=1029

[link1]
name=nodeB
ip=127.0.0.1
port=1027
cost=1

[link2]
name=nodeA
ip=127.0.0.1
port=1025
cost=10
```